# How to display the “miles” unit description after the distance in the GetLog view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am going to write the MVC, Microsoft exam (70-486) while preparing I come across one question frequently asking in the exam but I found a different answer in many websites.

Question is.

You need to display the “miles” unit description after the distance in the GetLog view. Which line of code
should you use to replace line GL21? (Each correct answer presents a complete solution.
Choose all that apply.)

[image]

A.
@log.Distance miles

B.
@Htrml.DisplayFor(model => log.Distance) miles

C.
@log.Distance.ToString() @Html.TextArea (“miles”)

D.
@Htmi.DisplayFor(model => log.Distance.ToString()+ ” miles”)

For Ref see this [link](http://www.aiotestking.com/microsoft/which-line-of-code-should-you-use-to-replace-line-gl21/)

In some website the answer given is A, B while some website given A, C. I know A is right, but between B and C which one right and why? Please someone guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. @log.Distance miles

Correct. The most straightforward and presumably most used syntax.

B. @Html.DisplayFor(model => log.Distance) miles

`DisplayFor` gives you the value **wrapped in a template most suited for the given datatype** (I assume `log.Distance` is an `int`).

Correct. Assuming you didn't mess up the template, if you made one yourself.

C. @log.Distance.ToString() @Html.TextArea (“miles”)

The `@log.Distance.ToString()` is correct, but the other part creates a textarea (multiline textbox) that has the **name attribute** `"miles"`.

Something like this: `<textarea name="miles"></textarea>`

Not correct.

D. @Html.DisplayFor(model => log.Distance.ToString()+ ” miles”)

`DisplayFor` gives you the value **wrapped in a template most suited for the given datatype**. In this case, the given datatype is a `string`, whereas the B answer had the given data type of `log.Distance`. It's still correct, but will render it using a template for a `string` rather than an `int` (or whatever type `log.Distance` is)

Correct. Assuming you didn't mess up the template, if you made it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer D. is incorect. If you try, you get this error:
"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."